# Django: Automatically executing statements in `manage.py shell`

Tags: python, django, shell

Every time I start a shell using `python manage.py shell`, I want a few lines to be executed automatically. (In my case it would be a few import lines in the style of `import django, my_app`.)

How do I do this?

Comment: You could install iPython and setup a startup script. Django will detect and use iPython if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up monkeypatching `IPython.frontend.terminal.embed.InteractiveShellEmbed.__call__` to add the definitions I wanted. (I know many people are opposed to monkeypatching but I find it to be a good solution in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

The package `django-extensions` does what you want. If you `pip install django-extensions`, and you can add the app as always (in your app list, then `run syncdb`), then you get a command called `shell_plus`.

That command loads *all* your models automatically if you run `python manage.py shell_plus`. Really handy! If you combine that the power of IPython you get a nice environment to interact with your models using the django ORM.

More information:

- For the package: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions
- For the docs on shell_plus: http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/shell_plus.html
- For the docs of django-extensions: http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/

Hope this helps. It might be less work than writing start-up scripts. As an extra django-extensions gives you great functions like `graph_models` (which can give you a png drawing of your database) and show_urls.